How to write a fits file from an ASCII file (astronomical spectrum)?
I have used iraf in the past to do this, and I have no problem when the pixel scale does not vary (although I have to manually edit the task parameters for it to work correctly). Now I am working with some model spectra that I need in fits format, and the rspectex task does not automatically convert the first column of the ASCII file into the real wavelength.
I have tried using astropy and specutils as well, but again, the dispersion is not correct. This can not be too complicated but I am running out of ideas. Have you done it before, or have any ideas?
Thanks!
data = np.loadtxt('spectrum.ascii')

hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(data)

hdr = fits.Header()
hdr['SIMPLE'] = True
hdr['OBJECT'] = 'object'
hdr['COMMENT'] = 'comment'

hdu.header = hdr
hdu.writeto('spectrum.fits')


Can you provide the first lines of the spectrum file so that one can see the exact format? ASCII includes a wide variety of formats and there is no general way to handle all correctly.

Generally, if this is a relatively simple input file, I will do this using astropy tables. So, it would be something like the following:
from astropy.table import Table    

# The names keyword is only needed if you want to change the column names.
spec = Table.read('spectrum.ascii',format='ascii',names=['wave','flux','err'])

# Add header comments
spec.meta['OBJECT']='object'
spec.meta['COMMENT']='comment'
  
# Save as FITS file
spec.write('spectrum.fits')

There are  a few caveats:

This approach does not write the object name and comments in the 0th extension header, only the first extension's header. I'm sure there's a way to do that, however.
The other thing that requires twiddling is the format given for reading an ascii file. You can look to the Table.read documentation for the details.

